# java regex for UUID

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse a String which has UUID in the below format

```
"&lt;urn:uuid:4324e9d5-8d1f-442c-96a4-6146640da7ce&gt;"
```

I have tried it parsing in below way, which works, however I think it would be slow

```
private static final String reg1 = ".*?";
private static final String reg2 = "([A-Z0-9]{8}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12})";
private static final Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile(re1 + re2, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

I am looking for a faster way and tried below, but it fails to match

```
private static final Pattern URN_UUID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^< urn:uuid:([^&])+&gt");
```

I am new to regex.
any help is appreciated.

\Aqura

Comment: Wait, you have `&lt;...` in your data but use `^<...` in your regex? That can't work.

Comment: Hint: if performance is really an issue - then keep in mind that the structure of a UUID is fixed. It has a fixed length, fixed sub fields, and so on. So it is just "coding work" to do use calls to substring() for example to 'cut out' the essential parts you are looking for. Then you only need to check for the initial length of your input ... in other words: you search for "uuid:"; then you "substring()" the 36 chars following the colon; and split on - from there.

Comment: Your `reg2` is wrong. An UUID is a hexadecimal number and as such only has letters A through F. Any other letter is wrong.

Comment: If the format of the string is always the same, i.e. `"&lt;urn:uuid:<actual uuid>&gt;"` then the expression isn't too complex: `&lt;urn:uuid:(.*)&gt;` (or maybe even `uuid:([a-f0-9\-]+)`.

Comment: *"however I think it would be slow"* Why you think so? Did you actually measure it?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use [UUID.fromString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#fromString-java.lang.String-), for instance with `if (s.startsWith("&lt;urn:uuid:") && s.endsWith("&gt;")) uuid = UUID.fromString(s.substring(13, s.length() - 4));`?  (The [“two problems” quote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Attributed) seems applicable here;  regular expressions should be used only when the work can’t be reasonably done without them.)

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, <code> uuid:([a-f0-9\-]+) </code> works.

Answer (score 23):

Your example of a faster regex is using a `<` where the input is `&lt;` so that's confusing.

Regarding speed, first, your UUID is hexadecimal, so don't match with `A-Z` but rather `a-f`. Second you give no indication that case is mixed, so don't use case insensitive and write the correct case in the range.

You don't explain if you need the part preceding the UUID. If not, don't include `.*?`, and you may as well write the literals for `re1` and `re2` together in your `final Pattern`. There's no indication you need DOTALL either.

```
private static final Pattern splitter =
  Pattern.compile("[a-f0-9]{8}(?:-[a-f0-9]{4}){4}[a-f0-9]{8}");
```

Alternatively, if you are measuring your Regular Expression's performance to be too slow, you might try another approach, for example:
Is each uuid preceded by "uuid:" as in your example? If so you can

1. find the first index of "uuid:" as *i*, then
2. substring 0 to *i*+5 [assuming you needed it at all], and
3. substring *i*+5 to *i*+41, if I counted that right (36 characters in length).

Along similar lines your faster regex could be:

```java
private static final Pattern URN_UUID_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("^&lt;urn:uuid:(.{36})&gt;");
```

OTOH if all your input strings are going to start with those exact characters, no need to do step 1 in the previous suggestion, just `input.substring(13, 49);`

Answer (score 0):

If this format don't be changed.
I think more fast way is use String.substring() method. 
Example:

```
String val = "&lt;urn:uuid:4324e9d5-8d1f-442c-96a4-6146640da7ce&gt;";
String sUuid = val.substring(13, 49);
UUID uuid =  UUID.fromString(sUuid);
```

Inside class String used char array for store data, in package java.lang.String:

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
...
113: /** The value is used for character storage. */
114: private final char value[];
...
}
```

Method 'String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)'  make the copy of array elements, from start to end index, and create new String on basis new array.
Copying of array it is a very fast operation.

Comment: Note that the OP isn't mentioning PARSING the UUID. But note that there is a significant chance that using fromString() is more expensive. You need a try catch there, and in using try/catch instead of if/else checking can add A TON of performance penalty. It isnt that bad these days, but still: bad practice.