# How to verify text in dialog box when it has dynamic text

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium to automate UI of our portal. One of the dialog boxes has the text

```
"Record with UUID:530d79e2-4d9a-4e8e-9114-da1431f0dd52 inserted successfully."
```

How do i put an assert for this text as UUID keeps changing every time? One workaround that I have is mentioned below.

```
Assert.assertTrue(string.contains("Record with UUID:");


Assert.assertTrue(string.contains("inserted successfully.");
```

But this to me looks like a bad approach. Any suggestions to do it in a cleaner way?

Comment: Dont you have any rest endpoint for this?

Comment: This is part of a UI test so the requirement is to validate the message displayed on the UI. There is a rest endpoint but this message is converted from the original message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [String#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) function, for example:

```
Assert.assertTrue(string.matches("Record with UUID:[0-9a-z\\-]+ inserted successfully."));
```

You can use more advanced regular expression for validating UUID, for example from this answer:[java regex for UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615731/java-regex-for-uuid)

```
Assert.assertTrue(
  string.matches("Record with UUID:[a-f0-9]{8}(-[a-f0-9]{4}){3}-[a-f0-9]{12} inserted successfully.")
);
```

or another:

```
Assert.assertTrue(
  string.matches("Record with UUID:[0-9a-fA-F]{8}(?:-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}){3}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12} inserted successfully.")
);
```

---

This page: [Regular Expression Test Page for Java](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) can be used to test regular expressions agains various input text.

Comment: Thanks all your suggested options work. The first one needs an extra '\'. It should be [0-9a-z\\-]+. Giving it a thumbs up... :)