# Java Regex for UUID with a prefix

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex for a prefix string + uuid. I know that UUID has the regex `"\b[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b"` but what would it look like if I were to add a prefix like `"id ="` on there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java regex for UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615731/java-regex-for-uuid)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
"\bid\s*=\s*[0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}\b"
```

- Starting and ending the line with word boundaries (`\b`) ensures it's not matching `fooid = ...` or `...-0123456789abBAR`
- Any number (`*`) of white spaces (`\s`) is allowed before and after the `=`
- I have removed the word boundaries in the middle of the UUID since I doubt that you want them there
- `[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-` can be replaced by `([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}` (repeating the part in parenthesis 3 times)

Comment: @roediGERhard thanks for the hint. I simplified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix `id =`  should go inside the word boundary \b delimiters:

```
"\bid = [0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}\b"
```

This way you avoid accidentally matching other words that happen to end with "id."

You also had unnecessary, extra word boundary anchors within the uuid regex. I've removed them.

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP's UUIDs look like but the word boundaries in the middle don't look right to me.